# Download CSV file after Login

Tags: r, csv, download, click, rvest

**The Question:**

How do I download the CSV file from the following link after logging in to the site?

- The site: https://rotogrinders.com/
- The link: [https://rotogrinders.com/grids/standard-projections-the-bat-x-3372510?site=draftkings/](https://rotogrinders.com/grids/standard-projections-the-bat-x-3372510?site=draftkings)

**What I have so far:**

```
rg.headers <- c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
rg.url <- "https://rotogrinders.com/"
rg.session <- html_session(rg.url, httr::add_headers(.headers=rg.headers))
rg.session <- rvest:::request_POST(rg.session, url = "https://rotogrinders.com/sign-in",
                                  body = list("username"="*****",
                                              "password"="*****"),
                                  encode = 'json')
bat.p_redirect <- jump_to(rg.session, "https://rotogrinders.com/grids/standard-projections-the-bat-x-3372510?site=draftkings")
```

Which logs me in and redirects me to the page with the *Download as CSV* button. I just don't know where to go from here to actually click the download button and save the .csv file where I would like it to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. The *Download as CSV* button has its own URL, so instead of redirecting to the page in the code above, I redirected to the button's URL and scraped from there.

```
bat.p_redirect = jump_to(rg.session, "https://rotogrinders.com/grids/standard-projections-the-bat-x-3372510.csv?site=draftkings")$response$content
writeBin(bat.p_redirect, "C:/.../BAT.P.csv")
```

If anyone has a more efficient solution, I'd love to hear it, but this way works well for me.